# Can you use Awaken on an Insect Swarm and affect the whole swarm?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, swarm

A swarm of insect technically counts as a single "creature", but Awaken only specifics targeting a "beast" or "plant". Note it doesn't say a *single* beast or plant, just a beast or plant. That being said a Swarm of Insects are called out as "Medium swarm of Tiny Beasts", so I can also see that awakening a swarm will just result in a single insect being awakened instead of the whole swarm, even though the Insect Swarm is the target "creature".

I was just thinking about this due to the nature of swarms as creatures. Obviously when you target a swarm with any other spell such as Magic Missile or Vicious Mockery, you're affecting the whole swarm, not just an individual insect who takes all of the affects. But I wonder if the same would apple to spells like Awaken, Polymorph, or teleport (Can you bring a whole swarm with you, or only 7-8 insects out of that swarm?).

Comment: The counting issue for swarms has been asked about before with the *polymorph* spell, so I’ve closed this as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov The problem with the swarm rules is that they count a swarm as a creature, except when they don't, without much clear guidance of when each is which.  On principle, I think "Awaken" is a different question than "Polymorph", just like Sacred Flame is a different question than Fireball.  OTOH, I don't think the _answers_ are going to be different or any better informed.

Comment: TheMonkeFist, You are welcome to make a case for why that question on polymorph doesn't answer your question and your (edited) question could be reopened.  If not, and if the linked question (and the one about wild shape linked there) does not answer yours, you might also consider: [Can the Conjure Animals spell summon swarms?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/129335/can-the-conjure-animals-spell-summon-swarms?rq=1), [Can swarms be pushed or pulled?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72757/23547)...

Comment: ...[How are swarms considered in terms of number of creatures?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/166874/23547), [What does Sacred Flame do to a swarm?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123287/23547)